# FlashMessage not removed from the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, flash-message

I have written a code  ASP.NET MVC. After the operation is successful/unsucessfull in the Controller I have used Vereyon.FlashMessage to display the flash message on the top of the page. The flash message is successfully shown in the top of the page but the problem is I cannot get rid of that flash message eve after dismiss. Also when I move to another page the flash message stays on the browser. How can I get rid of that?

My code for Controller is:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateWorkCategoryAndRate(WorkOrderDetailsViewModel mainModel)
        {
            try
            {
                var model = mainModel.WorkOrderRates;     
                var result = await _contractService.UpdateCompletedWorkOrderCategoryAndRate(model);
                FlashMessage.Confirmation("Rate/Work Order Categroy Edited Successfully for Work Order " + model.WorkOrderId);
                return RedirectToAction("View", "contracts", new { id = model.WorkOrderId });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                FlashMessage.Danger("Error Occured");
                return null;
            }
        }
```

I have used @Html.RenderFlashMessage() in layoyt.cshtml to diplay the flash Message.

```
 <div class="right_col" role="main">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        @Html.RenderFlashMessages()
                    </div>
                </div>
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
```

Also When I close this application say(app 1) and then open another application (app 2)  the flash message of app 1 still occurs on the top of the page (app 2) when using `@Html.RenderFlashMessages()`
How Can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's no longer working for me either.

As a workaround I used session storage (instead of cookie storage)

This is done by adding

FlashMessage.Transport = new FlashMessageSessionTransport();

in the startup.cs